# separation of concerns on two class

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am in doubt to apply the separation of concerns concept in two classes

I basically have my class

to create a match

```
class Match {
    constructor (players) {
      this.id = uuid.v4 (). toString ();
      this.players = players;
      this.isActive = false;
    }
    // Match rest methods ...
  }

  module.exports = Match;
```

and how I need a match collection to do a socket.io logic

or need an array of these matchs to access when needed

and i make this class Matches or MatchManager:

```
class Matches {
    constructor() {
      this.matches = [];
    }

    addMatch(match) {
      if(match){
        this.matches.push(match);
      }
    }
    getMatch(id){
      if(id){      
        return this.matches.find((match) => match.id = match )
      }else{
        return null;
      }

    }


  }

  module.exports = Matches;
```

In my class match I have my isActive
that I will start and finish a game using isActive setting to true or false

so a function
startMatch ()
and
endMatch ()

that I would need to change my isActive to true or false,
but I am unsure how to do this in a function (accessing a specific match)

and also with this design I have another problem

and another doubt
Could I create a match function to create a Match?

Comment: Not really helping you, but related.

https://blog.codinghorror.com/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager/

Comment: Also. Any problem with just using an array of Match?

Comment: @jhc no no have problem

Comment: So the idea of ​​the article would be to keep everything in one class following those aspects?

Comment: But following this I can't imagine how it could have defined attributes and a collection of a class,
could you help me with these two?

Comment: the idea of the article is that calling something a "manager" is usually a bad idea, as what does a manager do? Theses classes quickly become bloated.

Comment: Don't take the article too seriously, it was just slightly related to your post. My point specifically about your case is that maybe you don't need a Matches class, as at this moment it really doesn't do much (it's a list and does list stuff).But if it does have to exist, better use Matches (plural of Match), than MatchManager, as it is a list of matches (again plural), and doesn't do much else.

Comment: Could you help me how could you improve it?

I really can't imagine how I would create a function to declare that a match in a match collection is active or not

this is knotting my mind

Comment: I understood in this case I thought of the match to protect / delimit my attributes

Comment: Your Match class is completely fine, no problems there. And I don't want to discuss too much on style, but I just believe the Matches class is unecessary (at this point). All it does is do list related things, and therefore could simply be a list.

Declare at your program entry point (or where matches start existing), the matches = [], and you are good! Anyways, I prefer starting simpler and then making things complex as needed.

Comment: I understand
could you make an answer for me to vote positive?

Comment: I think I understood it would be kind of like in java

where I had an array of a class

hehe
but how would i do that in js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Less is more in programming.

Start with the simplest solution to a problem. Complicate the problem, your solution breaks, now find the next simplest solution to that problem. Reiterate.

If all your `Matches` class is do list oriented stuff, than maybe it should be a list instead.

I don't know how you are integrating with socket.io, but imagine the scenario where a new match is created.

```
// Declare a global matches list, on your app entry.
matches = []

// On a new match event, create a Match, and add to list.
app.on('newMatch', function(players){
    matches.push(new Match(players))
});
```

### Opinion

Don't make it harder for yourself by adding functionality/complexity that you MIGHT need. Add it when you need it. Much easier to maintain, and much faster to develop.

Comment: and if I want to create a function to start a match ie change isActive to true
in a match of this array
how would i get this?
Can you help me?

Comment: Not sure what you are building, but is isActive necessary? Like for example, what would a match be initiated and not be active? My default value for that would be True, instead of False like it is right now.